# Unparseable Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch-2.0

I have data with an integer year field. I'm trying to give a weight to more recent data, so that results that would otherwise tie are sorted by the year in reverse-chronological order.

```
        {
            "query": {
                "function_score": {
                    "functions": [
                        {
                            "gauss": {
                                "year": {
                                    "origin": "2016",
                                    "scale": "50"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "query": "This is replaced by the main query",
                    "boost_mode": "sum"
                },
                "_source": 1
            }
        }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
parse_exception: failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [VALUE_NUMBER]
```

I can't tell what I'm doing wrong, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the "_source": 1 at the wrong nesting level. It should've been one level up.